# not error on handler but not display image

Tags: android, imageview, handler, runnable

i not have get error but can't display image on activity

MainActivity :

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
EditText inputUrl;
OnClickListener getImageBtnOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Editable ed = inputUrl.getText();
        Drawable image = ImageOperations(context,ed.toString(),"image.jpg");
        final ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context);
        imgView.setImageDrawable(image);
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                 public void run() { 
                 imgView.setImageResource(R.id.imageView1);

                 } 
            }, 10000);     

    }
};
```

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        inputUrl = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1));
        inputUrl.setSingleLine();
        inputUrl.setTextSize(11);
        Button getImageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        getImageButton.setOnClickListener(getImageBtnOnClick);
    }


private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

how to fix it ? display and run image with interval ? thank's

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.id.imageView1);
```

and use

```
image.setImageDrawable(image);  // image is your drawable
```

in your handler so that it becomes,

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                 public void run() { 
                 image.setImageDrawable(image);                   

                 } 
            }, 10000);
```

Comment: but i getting resources from URL, how to get that?

Comment: setImageResource() Sets a drawable as the content of the ImageView on which it is called.

Comment: I have updated my post, you need to use image.setImageDrawable(your_drawable);

Comment: you are using Drawable image = ImageOperations(context,ed.toString(),"image.jpg"); which gives you a drawable, and I suppose you want to set this drawable to your imageview. But as you are using imgView.setImageResource(R.id.imageView1); which takes a resource id as parameter,it does not work. You have to use image.setImageDrawable(image); and pass your drawable.

Comment: change modifier of 'image to 'final

Comment: Please do it and try.

Comment: image.setImageDrawable(image); this is code from you but it having error

Comment: can you fix it ? i will send you that project, i change but always having error